# Direction of friction and normal

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, metric-tensor, friction

We know that friction can be calculated using

F=uN
Where u is just a constant for two surfaces in contact.

So ,  direction of friction should be the same as of normal but it doesn't happen.
Is coefficient of friction also a tensor quantity because direction of normal is not the same as direction of friction ??

If not then what's the reason for it ??

Note: i am a high school student and read about tensor here!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am8q3.jpg)

Is the u referred in the picture similar to u in above equation ( in terms of direction changing coefficient not meaning)??

Comment: This question is not very clear. Why is there an issue that the normal is not in the direction of friction? And then this question "*If not then what's the reason for it ??*" what are you talking about? What is "it"?

Comment: Direction of normal for a body kept on a table is perpendicular but friction is perpendicular to normal bur why??

Comment: I am still not following. You are just asking why friction only acts parallel to the surface? What does this have to do with tensors?

Comment: Oh ok. Your edit makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the typical introductory model of friction, $f=\mu N$ is *not* a vector equation. It is just an equation relating the *magnitude* of the friction force $f$ to the *magnitude* of the normal force $N$.

If you wanted to write out a vector equation, it would be
$$\mathbf f=\mu N\hat s$$
where $\hat s$ is the unit vector parallel to the surface in the direction opposite the motion (or impending motion) of the surfaces.

I could see a tensor $\boldsymbol\mu$ for the friction coefficient if you had some irregular surface where sliding in one direction has more friction than sliding in another direction, or where motion in one direction effects friction in the other direction. Then I suppose you would have something like
$$\mathbf f=N\boldsymbol\mu\hat s=N
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    \mu_{xx} & \mu_{xy} \\
    \mu_{yx} & \mu_{yy} \\
    \end{matrix}\right)\cdot
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    s_x  \\
    s_y \\
    \end{matrix}\right)$$

Although I can't imagine a scenario where the off-diagonal elements of this tensor would constantly be non-zero. This would suggest that, for example, pushing an object purely in one direction would cause friction to start pushing it in another direction, which seems odd to me.

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: @Aakankshasharma My answer still stands. Normally when writing out $f=\mu N$, $f$ and $N$ are not vectors. They are just magnitudes. Typically $\mu$ is not a tensor.

Comment: But we assign directions in the fbd of these forces.

Comment: @AnkitKumar So? The FBD doesn't determine the model you use for friction. Once again $f=\mu N$ is not a vector equation. The FBD has not impact on this